# XPATH to match contents of all child nodes within a parent element

Tags: xml, xpath

Suppose i have XMLs like this,

```
<a><b>text</b></a>
```

and

```
<a>text</a>
```

how do i write a generic xpath to match all the contents within the element `<a>` irrespective of the child nodes (`<b>`) instead of writing `/a/b` and `/a` because I can have any child node for the element `<a>`.

Comment: Do you mean something like this `//a//text()`? This should match `text` in both `xml` samples

Comment: i tried with //a//text()... i am not getting the desired output..it doesn't seem to consider the contents within the child node.

Answer (score 0):

To get the result equal to `/a` on your first XML sample **and** equal to `/a/b` on your second XML sample, you can use the following expression :

```
//a/descendant-or-self::*[not(*)]
```

The XPath return descendant of `a` or `a` itself whichever is the *leaf element* i.e element without child.

For demo, consider the following sample XML :

```
<root>
    <a><b>text b</b></a>
    <a>text a</a>
    <a><c>text c</c></a>
    <a><c><d>text d</d></c></a>
</root>
```

When the XPath above is executed the result will be :

```
<b>text b</b>
<a>text a</a>
<c>text c</c>
<d>text d</d>
```

**<kbd>[`demo`](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/kSn-akDlf)</kbd>**